# Is there a benefit to taking whey protein to increase glutathione level compared to the body's natural production?

Tags: immune-system, proteins

Glutathione is a strong antioxidant needed for many processes in the body. High levels of glutathione have been linked to strong immune systems, heavy metals elimination, lower inflammation, lower chronic diseases and the general good function of every kind of cells in the body.

Glutathione is naturally produced by the body by using the 3 amino acids cysteine, glycine and glutamate. Cysteine seems to be the limiting factor since it is available in lower quantities than the others.

Some source ([Mercola](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2010/04/10/can-you-use-food-to-increase-glutathione-instead-of-supplements.aspx), [Wasington's Blog](http://www.washingtonsblog.com/2013/11/glutathione.html)) say that undenatured whey protein increases glutathione in the body by a slightly different mechanism, perhaps by bypassing several steps of the production.

I am wondering if whey supplementation increases glutathione levels beyond what can be achieved by supplying the body with enough cysteine, glycine and glutamate. Is the effect observed only caused by the high cysteine content of whey compared to other protein sources?